# Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090288/usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)

I am getting this error after sending 7-8 builds to QA of my company.
Thing tried :

1. Reinstalled the appstore distribution provisioning profiles .
2. Restated the xcode device.
3. changed the bundle identifier in info.plist.

And moreover this error is coming alternately and when i am trying to do the clean build.
alternately means first time this error is coming and next time it is gone and then again it is coming and then next time is gone.
Can someone tell me what the hell is happening, i have nailed my head for hours.

Answer (score 1):

There is some good advice on a related question [/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090288/usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1/2221435#2221435):

> ...you can right click the error
>   message in Xcode and choose expand to
>   get more details, including a
>   description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also was struggling with the 'Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1' error message.

Here is how I solved it

Right-click on info.plist (or whatever your application plist name is) look at it's targets. Make sure the box to the left is UNCHECKED. This is the default state.

Targeting the files don't work fine for the info.plist.