# Codesign failed with exit code doesn't fix

Tags: iphone, sdk

I have faced with this erros !

> /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit
>   code 1

I am read 10000000 ways to solve this problem I don't know why doesn't fix !!!!

For example :

I checked CODE_SIGNING_IDENTIFY and matches with my provising profile ! 
On Info.plist target the left side option is UNCHECKED
I create this profile step by step with IOS DEV CENTER wizard 
my keychain is valid and is login

THIS DRIVE ME CRAZY !!! I DON"T KNOW WHAT SHOULD I DO I NEVER THIS PROBLEM

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your keychain Apple world  wide Certificate , never user ALWAYS TRUST with your certificate :) hope this help

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEEES Thank youuuuuuuu works great now ...  brilliant idea

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try would be to create another project from template and see if it will build to device without the error. If it does, the problem is a setting in that particular project (which is likely.) If not, you may have certificate problem (rare.)

In my experience the problem is almost always in the info.plist file as per [this previous answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090288/usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)