# Xcode Error: Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, exit-code, codesign

I have no idea why I am getting this error.  I believe that I have all the correct provisioning profiles and such.  I did just move to a new computer but I did also bring over the private keychain developer key.  I have my developer files synced with Dropbox so I didn't need to move over the Xcode project.  Here is the error:

```
   CodeSign "/Users/michaellindahl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fraction_Calculator-cgirhuuvywfnsyenisucsuauquoz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Fraction Calculator Pro.app"
    cd "/Users/michaellindahl/Dropbox/Xcode/lindahl studios/FractionCalculator"
    setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "iPhone Developer: Michael Lindahl (MXXX0X0XXB)" "--resource-rules=/Users/michaellindahl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fraction_Calculator-cgirhuuvywfnsyenisucsuauquoz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Fraction Calculator Pro.app/ResourceRules.plist" --entitlements "/Users/michaellindahl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fraction_Calculator-cgirhuuvywfnsyenisucsuauquoz/Build/Intermediates/Fraction Calculator.build/Debug-iphoneos/Fraction Calculator Pro.build/Fraction Calculator Pro.xcent" "/Users/michaellindahl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fraction_Calculator-cgirhuuvywfnsyenisucsuauquoz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Fraction Calculator Pro.app" 

CSSM_SignData returned: 8001094A
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fraction_Calculator-cgirhuuvywfnsyenisucsuauquoz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Fraction Calculator Pro.app: unknown error -2070=fffffffffffff7ea
    Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: did this work on your old machine before you moved to the new machine?  Are you running the same revision of Xcode on the new machine?

Comment: @Richard I believe the only thing that has changed is I moved from a Snow Leopard Desktop to a Lion Laptop.  If they are both Lion can I share the files and be fine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090288/usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've almost certainly got corrupted certs :

Revoke old certs, generate new ones, new provisioning profile, the works, magic happens again

Answer (score 2):

This seems senseless, but I simply locked and then unlocked the login keychain and the problem went away.  On reflection, the problem occurred after I had added a new certificate to the keychain.  Maybe the addition of this additional certificate (unrelated to the current project) caused the problem.

Comment: My saviour! This fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try going through all of the steps in the [Managing Devices and Digital Identities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html) document. This should help you verify that your machine is correctly set up.