# Install on Device give Error : Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, xcode, keychain

I refer this links
[Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017756/command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)
 and [Xcode Error: Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071691/xcode-error-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)
but not find solution.
I spent lots of time to solve and try this issue  but  I can't sove it .

Error is below.

`/Users/macmini2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CliniCalc-euqpjsnetzgblefamkvsxhinzomp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CliniCalc.app: The operation was cancelled by the user.
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1`

I used Xcode 5.1.

Comment: see this thread if it helps u
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062285/codesign-the-operation-was-cancelled-by-the-user

Comment: As told: You cancelled the build operation...

Comment: I did not cancell build operation .It's cancel by it self.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it . I just restart my Mac and error is fixed.Thanks for helping

Comment: Oh my god!! This is the best and simplest answer ever xD. I got this problem for some weeks. Thank you very much :)!

Comment: Same with you..waste me two days to solve this bug. Finally just restart my MAC then solved... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378604/xcode9-code-sign-error-in-ionic3-project-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with