# Code Sign Error - xCode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090288/usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)

I am aware this question is very frequently asked.

I tried in every way but i get this error:

```
    CodeSign /Users/iacopocricelli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Prova2-bvdyofacwyoznwbxshegsvewaoan/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Prova2.app
        cd /Users/iacopocricelli/Desktop/Projects/Prova2
        setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate

setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
            /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 48e8251951b5605143fe428c32f588209d2c1ce2 --resource-rules=/Users/iacopocricelli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Prova2-bvdyofacwyoznwbxshegsvewaoan/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Prova2.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/iacopocricelli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Prova2-bvdyofacwyoznwbxshegsvewaoan/Build/Intermediates/Prova2.build/Debug-iphoneos/Prova2.build/Prova2.xcent /Users/iacopocricelli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Prova2-bvdyofacwyoznwbxshegsvewaoan/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Prova2.app

        /Users/iacopocricelli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Prova2-bvdyofacwyoznwbxshegsvewaoan/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Prova2.app: The operation was cancelled by the user.Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I am registered as developer.
I install all certificate.
I checked that there are no duplicate certificates.
I checked the bundle identifier.
I checked the code signing in the build settings.
I install the correct mobile provision as Q253------.xxxxx.* and my bundle identifier are xxxxxx.myname
I tried to create other projects-

How can i solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried all the solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090288/usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1

Comment: yes, i tried all the solutions in this site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Click on on the organizer window on the top right corner of Xcode. Then click on the devices tab. Then on Provisioning Profiles under Library on the left and click the refresh icon on the bottom right corner.

If you have the bundle identifier and the Code Signing setup properly in the project this will usually fix most of the code signing issues.