# Mac OS X Archive (.app) crashed on test Mac machine: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: macos, portability, freetype, install-name-tool

I am working on a Mac application, which is running fine on my machine which is a development machine.
The project has quite a few dylib files, the dependancies for which I had to solve using

`install_name_tool -change`

I used @executable_path in the above command. After doing this, the program works fine on my machine, when I move the .app file to test environment it fails..

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

0   libfreetype.6.dylib             0x001f736b **FT_CMap_New** + 105

1   libfreetype.6.dylib             0x0022d1a4 **tt_face_build_cmaps** + 516

2   libfreetype.6.dylib             0x00229f0a **sfnt_load_face** + 1424

3   libfreetype.6.dylib             0x00200cbe **tt_face_init** + 231

4   libfreetype.6.dylib             0x001f5fb4 **open_face** + 218

5   libfreetype.6.dylib             0x001f5bf1 **FT_Open_Face** + 528

6   libfreetype.6.dylib             0x001f59db **FT_New_Face** + 68

Looking at the bold characters one can make out that the problem is in freetype dylib. But why is it giving problems? I have included the .dylib file in the `my_app.app/Contents/Frameworks/` directory.

Is this why the problem is caused?

Answer (score 1):

This error is seen because the location of the font supplied to freetype was incorrect.

The client did not have the supplied font file (ttf) on his machine.

When I supplied the ttf file along with the bundle, it was fixed.!