# Xcode: code sign identity - core plot framework for sandbox entitlements

Tags: xcode, core-plot, codesign, entitlements

I transfered my *mac app* to *itunes connect* and received following message:

> App sandbox not enabled - The following executables must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list. Refer to the App Sandbox page for more information on sandboxing your app.

So, I enabled the sandbox entitlements and run the build. I got the notice:

> CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS specified without specifying CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY. It is not possible to add entitlements to a binary without signing it.

Next, I selected the provisioning profile from target -> build settings and run again. So, I got a error that means my code sign identity isn't correct, maybe during I compiled the core-plot framework.

> code object is not signed at all...
>   In subcomponent: ./Contents/Frameworks/CorePlot.framework ... Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

How I can do it sign?

Comment: What's the error exactly u r getting?

Comment: The error ist exactly: code object is not signed at all... In subcomponent: ./Contents/Frameworks/CorePlot.framework ... Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Comment: See this link for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263967/codesign-of-dropbox-api-fails-in-xcode-4-6-3-code-object-is-not-signed-at-all

Comment: google your error. you will surely find alot of hint to help yourself out.

Comment: Alright, to sign the framework I added **--deep** to the **Target -> Build Settings -> Other Code Signing Flags**.

Comment: The --deep flag on release just fixed something I've been struggling with for 3 days on and off! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer...

> Alright, to sign the framework I added **--deep** to the **Target** -> **Build Settings** -> **Other >Code Signing Flags**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. With this solution Core Plot 2 works in a arm64 build :)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with XCode 6, you should sign each embedded framework first (sign inside, and then outside), and then sign the app. Make sure you have all the required values in your Info.plist files. There are more details in codesigning [technote 2206](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html)