# Codesigning included framework

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, frameworks, codesign

OK, after lots of desperate attempts to make Connection Kit work, I've finally made it to create a project get to compile - yay!. Oh, wait, I didn't say it actually runs. It just compiled without any error - yay, again.

But now I guess I have to deal with linking issues.

```
CodeSign /Users/drkameleon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ftpTest5-fnzabvxlmdwqwpbcsglidslbijzn/Build/Products/Debug/ftpTest5.app/Contents/Frameworks/ConnectionKit.framework/Versions/A
    cd "/Users/drkameleon/Code/##Tests/ftpTest5"
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate

Signing Identity:     "-"

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules /Users/drkameleon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ftpTest5-fnzabvxlmdwqwpbcsglidslbijzn/Build/Products/Debug/ftpTest5.app/Contents/Frameworks/ConnectionKit.framework/Versions/A

Warning: usage of --preserve-metadata with option "resource-rules" (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)!
/Users/drkameleon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ftpTest5-fnzabvxlmdwqwpbcsglidslbijzn/Build/Products/Debug/ftpTest5.app/Contents/Frameworks/ConnectionKit.framework/Versions/A: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/drkameleon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ftpTest5-fnzabvxlmdwqwpbcsglidslbijzn/Build/Products/Debug/ftpTest5.app/Contents/Frameworks/ConnectionKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CURLHandle.framework
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Any idea what this means guys? What am I supposed to do?

---

The accepted answer here ([Codesign of Dropbox API fails in Xcode 4.6.3: "code object is not signed at all"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263967/codesign-of-dropbox-api-fails-in-xcode-4-6-3-code-object-is-not-signed-at-all)) basically suggests using the `--deep` signing flag. But neither this seems to be supported in Xcode6+, nor does it work for me (the exact same errors are being produced).

Comment: Code sign has failed. Check your project settings, and make sure you have provided the right signing identities.

Comment: @GoodSp33d Well, of course it has failed. But it has nothing to do with identities (I've tried it with a proper signing identity, and it fails as well -- yep, the exact same identities I've used to sign my over-40 apps in the store...)

Comment: Yeah I have incorrectly marked this question as a duplicate.  However it's always difficult to know what has and has not been tried so this question should be re-opened. I will flag it for moderator attention.  However I am wondering what the effects of having a directory in your source tree containing a `#` will have on functionality; I certainly wouldn't have used that character.

Comment: @trojanfoe Well, those "#" most definitely don't look good (it's a habit from my Windows days, I guess lol), but it usually doesn't cause an issue at all - and I do tend to name folders with sharp signs at the beginning. As for the issue, I'm not 100% sure, but I believe I'm close to solving it. (I've actually discovered that applying the very same identity + `--deep` to every single one of the nested projects (using ConnectionKit, means at least 2 other nested/children Xcode projects, with tons of libraries) may do the trick). I'll post it as answer if it works. :-)