# IBM Worklight/MobileFirst 6.x/7.0 - "Code object is not signed at all." error with buildtime.sh script

Tags: ios, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst, codesign

I am having an error when uploading my Worklight Application into iTunes.

The application validation fails with the following error:

> Invalid Signature. Code object is not signed at all. The binary at
>   path **[MyApp.app/buildtime.sh]** contains an invalid signature. Make sure
>   you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not
>   an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the
>   code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which
>   override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the
>   bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode,
>   not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings
>   are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory
>   in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information,
>   please consult
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

My problem is that I submitted the same application 2 weeks ago and it was working fine. Today's version has only the www/ folder content changed, and it fails with this error.

I googled the issue, and found [Codesign of Dropbox API fails in Xcode 4.6.3: "code object is not signed at all"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263967/codesign-of-dropbox-api-fails-in-xcode-4-6-3-code-object-is-not-signed-at-all), but I tried adding the --deep option and this haven't worked for me.

Can this related to something with buildtime.sh script? As I read it, it seems just updating buildtime value in the worklight.plist file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
# 5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2006, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
# US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
# disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.

# Update buildtime in project 
echo -n ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/worklight.plist | xargs -0
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :buildtime `date +\"%s\"`"
```

Also when googling the issue I found some similar issue at:
https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues/918 and they seems to use hybrid applications with sh scripts, which make me believe that the issue is related to the buildtime.sh script.

I deleted the buildtime script, and deleted run script phase on my Xcode project, and this time it is not giving the error.

Is it safe to do so?

Anyone encountered the same error with a Worklight project? Is it related to buildtime.sh script or new Apple policy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blog post about this issue in the MFP Developer Center: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/05/01/recent-changes-in-apples-app-submission-process/

The problem is that Apple is now also checking whether .sh files that are included in the application bundle (.ipa file) are signed or not.

In a Worklight/MobileFirst Platform-based application there happens to be one such .sh file, `buildtime.sh`, that is being added to the bundle. There is no reason for this file to be in the resulting bundle. The file is needed only during build-time, not run-time.

There is a simple workaround: *remove* (*do not* delete) the `buildtime.sh` file from the target configuration in Xcode (in Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources).

There are also iFixes available (IBM APAR PI39826, Worklight/MFP Studio/CLI only; no Server change needed) from [IBM Fix Central](http://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/):

- 6.0.0.2-IF201504301500
- 6.1.0.2-IF201504301501
- 6.2.0.1-IF201504301522
- 6.3.0.0-IF201504301455
- 7.0.0.0-IF201504301556

This iFix is meant only for:

- Newly created applications
- Applications that their native folder is deleted and re-generated

By using the iFix these applications will not have the `buildtime.sh` file in the target configuration.

Existing applications must only simply remove the .sh file from the target configuration as mentioned above, followed by a re-build in Xcode.

Comment: So do you confirm that if I deleted the buildtime.sh script and the run script phase related to it, then submitted to the App Store, I will have no risk? (I tested on device after doing so, and it seems to be ok, but want to know if there is any risk for the submitted version to have issues or to be rejected for that)

Comment: If you removed the buldtime.sh from the located specified in my answer you should be OK. Do not delete it from the project itself, just the reference in the Build Phases section in Xcode.

Comment: I already submitted 9 hours ago with deleted buildtime.sh , is there any impact on this submitted binary?

Comment: If you submitted it w/out the .sh file then it should pass if that was the only other error you had the previous time you submitted; again, the important part is to remove the reference from the Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources section). If you've removed the file and compiled the project and it works and then submitted it, then it should pass the App Store validation.