# MobileFirst 7.0 App giving "ERROR itms-90035" on submission to apple app store

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to submit the new version of my MobileFirst 7.0 ios app to apple store but as soon as I submit, it gives me following error:

[image]

I am using XCode 6.3.1 on Yosemite. I have also added my Distribution certificate and Provisioning Profile to it but it still give me the error that your code is not at all signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to recent changes Apple has done.

To fix it: remove (do not delete) the buildtime.sh file from the target configuration in Xcode (in Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources).

Read the following for more information:

- [Recent changes to Apple’s app submission review process](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/05/01/recent-changes-in-apples-app-submission-process/)
- [IBM Worklight/MobileFirst 6.x/7.0 - "Code object is not signed at all." error with buildtime.sh script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979863/ibm-worklight-mobilefirst-6-x-7-0-code-object-is-not-signed-at-all-error-wi/29980589#29980589)