# Cocoa osx itunes code signing error dropbox bundle format is ambiguous (could be app or framework)

Tags: macos, frameworks, itunes, code-signing, dropbox-api

I submmited my app for Mac to iTunes and after that I received an email from iTunes.

Basically it says this:

"**Unable to Sign** - This package doesn't meet the current code signing requirements. For more information, see the Code Signing and Application Sandboxing Guide and Technical Note 2206.

Specifically, codesign generated the following error:

.../Payload/myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Dropbox.framework/Dropbox: bundle format is ambiguous (could be app or framework)

**Malformed Framework** - The framework bundle Dropbox (myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Dropbox.framework) must contain a symbolic link 'Dropbox' -> 'Versions/Current/Dropbox'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information."

This is my framework structure:

[image]

My app uses the Dropbox framework. I installed it following the Dropbox instructions. How can I solve this?

Need help please. Thanks in advance.

I tried doing this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24418689/3065901 but I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: [This very related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263967/codesign-of-dropbox-api-fails-in-xcode-4-6-3-code-object-is-not-signed-at-all) has answers that are likely to help you out.

Comment: It looks like you're using the Sync/Datastores OS X SDK: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/osx The Dropbox.framework in that download does have the mentioned sym link though: $ ls -la Dropbox.framework/ ... Dropbox -> Versions/Current/Dropbox Does your copy not have that? Maybe try downloading a fresh copy, in case yours got changed somehow.