# Cocoapod issue not able to run on simulator

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have created my cocoapod and cross check in sample project but it is showing everytime this error.

[image]

I googled and found solution

1. Reset content and setting
2. Clear derived data
3. Clean and build
4. Restart xcode

But non of them works

i tried on device

[image]

Comment: Close and open simulator.

Comment: done still not working

Comment: And what happens when you try and run it on a different simulator device?

Comment: see the pic when tried in device
i'm not using that profile

Comment: Not on a device. On a simulator device, you can choose 'Phone 6' 'Iphone 6s' etc..

Comment: yes i tried also it is giving error as shown in 1st pic

Comment: in device logs i'm getting :  framework did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist

But it is present

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are opening the newly created .workspace file rather than your original project.

Comment: Make sure your extension bundle ID is prefixed with your apps bundle ID

Comment: this is my budel ID : com.marvel.CocoaTest

Project and Root folder name : CocoaTest

Comment: Try building on an actual device

Comment: build failed it is showing another provision profile which i'm not using

see pic above

Comment: Go into target of framework and change profile to automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer for debugging.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26129829

Basically you need to look at ~/Library/logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log for the source of the errors.

You need to consider the fact that the simulator is not linking files properly than any specific cocoapod issue.

Alternately, the problem could be related to code signing.
Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17402788/2569560

If details like the Podspec and the simulator log were shared, perhaps we could be of more help.