# Jenkins error: /usr/bin/codesign --force failed exit code 1

Tags: ios, jenkins, xcode6, continuous-integration, osx-yosemite

I am configuring CI for my IOS project on MAC yosemite-OS and got on problem:

error: `/usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules --sign /Users/mitul/Desktop/jenkins_ios_profile/PCertificates.p12 --resource-rules=/var/folders/rj/cc6d38nn53v6tk8y4jn7ghkr0000gp/T/42RbMszHQX/Payload/XXX.app/ResourceRules.plist /var/folders/rj/cc6d38nn53v6tk8y4jn7ghkr0000gp/T/42RbMszHQX/Payload/XXX.app failed with error 1`

even my build and archive are getting success but not able to make .ipa file

even tried all possibilities from this 
[/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090288/usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)  but no luck

Please help me what I am missing to do

My Xcode configuration is as follows:

Custom xcodebuild arguments:

`CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH=/Users/mitul/Public/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/ResourceRules.plist`

rest are all with default setting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I unchecked the code signing checkbox in jenkins project configuration and it started building, hope it can help some else too!