# XCode 7, no identity found

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

My certificate expires on 2017 and the provisioning profile is active.
It used to work very well several days ago but for some reason I can't build my app anymore.
This is the error I get :

```
C9B531B60712E22D5C0892366E9C330555929A3C: no identity found
*** error: Couldn't codesign /Users/cherif/Apps/Parkisseo/NoPark/Build/Products/
Debug-iphoneos/NoPark.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib: 
codesign failed with exit code 1
```

What should I check ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090288/usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Comment: In my case the problem was a smartcard in my mac mini with invalid certificate...

Answer (score 2):

Here are some solutions I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090288/usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1/5751173#5751173)

> Check the CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY property in your build settings. Is your
>   provisioning profile selected there?   You also need to enter a valid
>   bundle identifier in your apps .plist.   The identifier has to match
>   the one you provided when generating the profile.   Apple has some
>   notes on that [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2009/tn2242.html).
>
> Apple also has a collection of code signing problems with solutions in
>   a document: [Technical Note TN2407 Code Signing Troubleshooting
>   Index](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/TN2407)

Another solution could be something to do with keychain access. This may solve your problem:

> So, in Keychain Access, click on the Apple Worldwide Developer
>   Relations Certificate Authority certificate, select **Get Info**. 
>   Then, expand the Trust settings, and for the combo box for "**When
>   using this certificate:**", choose "**System Defaults**".

It could also be that Xcode is confused between 2 accounts. Make sure you are using only one.

If none of these work, please get back to me.

Source: [/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090288/usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1/5751173#5751173)