# iOS: Remove duplicate objects in array of dictionarties(Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, build

```js
{
    rid = 374824705969;
    uuid = "1838346268_374823983610_2016-08-08T07:32:08.679GMT";
},
{

    rid = 374824705969;
    uuid = "1838346268_374823983610_2016-08-08T07:32:08.679GMT";
},
{
    rid = 374824706065;
    uuid = "1838346268_374823983610_2016-08-08T07:32:22.680GMT";
}
```

Hello. I have a response as above. I have created a DTO class to handle this response.
The DTO class “TESTDTO”. 
once i get the response I’m assigning it as below:
let testDTO = [TESTDTO]
testDTO = jsonResponse.array

now i want to remove the duplicate items from TESTDTO array with “rid” key.
How to filter testDTO array for duplicate elements. i want only unique elements in array.i'm using swift 2.2.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36972411/xcode-7-no-identity-found

Comment: It may be due to various reasons, it is not possible to provide you a precise solution.Need more information.