# "Codesign" exited with code 1 error while debugging in ios device in .NET MAUI 7

Tags: ios, macos, maui, visual-studio-2022

There is "Codesign" exited with code 1 issue when try to build iOS app using visual studio 2022 for mac.

I have been trying to debug the .net maui app using physical iPhone(iPhone 7 plus) device but when I try to run the app using visual studio 2022 to debug with physical iPhone(iPhone 7 plus) device or any iPhone simulator I'm getting "Codesign" exited with code 1 issue. I tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding it several times and also deleting the bin folder but it doesn't fix the issue. The below is the error that is thrown when building the app in IOS.

/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.4.7099/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(3,3): Error MSB6006: "codesign" exited with code 1.
[The Image of the issue]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js6cl.png)

I already tried all answers related to this in stackoverflow it is not working
[/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090288/usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Environment: visual studio 2022 for mac
.NET MAUI version: MAUI 7.0
Device: Iphone 7 plus

Comment: Create a new MAUI project with default template and can it run on an iphone simulator?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Never mind. It worked correctly using vs code.

Comment: How did you resolve this? Same issue

Comment: hey buddy. Sorry for late reply. Please check if have created and configured the certificates and profiles correctly. In visual studio you need to check the bundle signing if the created profile and certificate is coming. If not the issue is you failed to follow the publish steps in .net maui correctly. Check .Net maui publishing doc.